# Rodrigues' Formula In Four Dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, determinant, rotations

I found [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/283007638_Simple_Double_and_Isoclinic_Rotations_with_a_Viable_Algorithm_MATHEMATICAL_SCIENCES_AND_APPLICATIONS_E-NOTES_8_1_1-14_2020) paper on [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) for $4$ dimensions, but I don't really see the connection to the $3$-dimensional formula.  What I want to know, given orthogonal unit vectors $a_0,a_1\in\mathbf{R}^4$ and some $v\in\mathbf{R}^4$, how do I rotate $v$ around $(a_0,a_1)$ by $\pi/2$?  In other words, assuming $v$ is a unit vector and orthogonal to $\langle a_0,a_1\rangle$ (the other cases should be easy to derive), how do I (efficiently) find the unit vector $v_\text{rot}$ orthogonal to $\langle a_0,a_1,v\rangle$ such that $\det(a_0,a_1,v,v_\text{rot})=1$?  I believe this should uniquely determine $v_\text{rot}$?

What I got so far is that I *believe* I can compute $v_\text{rot}$ as $$(v_\text{rot})_j:=\sum_{\pi\in S_4:\pi(4)=j}\text{sgn}(\pi)\prod_{i=1}^{3}A_{\pi(i),i}$$ for $A:=(a_0,a_1,v)$ because this is the unique vector $d$ such that $\det(a_0,a_1,v,w)=\langle d,w\rangle$ and to maximize this inner product while keeping $\|w\|=1$ the solution is $w=d$, is that correct?  If yes, is this already the fastest algorithm?  Rodrigues' formula seems to be optimized for $\mathbf{R}^3$ while my approach would work in any dimension, which makes me think that it's probably not the best.

Comment: That $4d$ Rodrigues formula looks interesting but we don't necessarily need it for the rotation you describe. See [this related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4369308/949989).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I couldn't find the answer to my question there but I added some thoughts to my question above, do they make sense?

Comment: TL;DR. Looks like a reinvention of the wheel. My link describes the four basic rotations that keep coordinate planes fixed. If you want a rotation that keeps the $(a_0,a_1)$-plane fixed then sandwich your rotation into a coordinate transformation that maps your plane to, say, the $x-y$-plane.

Comment: But isn't that a similar problem, I need a coordinate rotation which rotates the $a_0$-$a_1$-plane to the $x$-$y$-plane, so I need to find two further vectors to complete the orthogonal system and the determinant should be $1$.